# Implementing circular scroller in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a jquery plugin to simulate a vertical marquee. I need it to support:

1. Scroll any opaque (unstructured) content. No li, no div. The user can even paste from Word.
2. Automatic constant scroll velocity.
3. Pause on hover.
4. Circular scroll - after scrolling to end, continue smoothly from the beginning. No scroll back, no visible jump.

I tried all the tickers, serialScroll, carousels, etc... Most require some structure, list, constant width/height items. Also they scroll by full items (scroll, wait, scroll).
But the biggest blocker is requirement 4. None provide "fake" tail to smoothly restart scrolling.

Have I missed something, or I'll have to write this by myself?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by a 'vertical marquee'. Do you want text, for instance, to scroll vertically as one big block like movie credits that just endlessly loop (or wrap) or something? Like, say you had a block of text that was 100px high and 100px wide. And you had a marquee area of 200px... You would want this block of text to scroll down and then have the hidden parts magically wrap to the top and continue scrolling? If this is what you mean, let me know and I'll see what I can do to make that happen for ya.

Comment: Very close. I've 100x150 block. I need it to scroll upwards, and when content has fully disappeared up, it restarts from below. See http://www.in4gan.co.il/%D7%92%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%92%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA.ashx/%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%90_%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%98%D7%99_%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%90_%D7%98%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%99 for the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 live examples of what you want:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/10/scroll-up-headline-reader

http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/10/automatic-news-ticker-with-vertical.html

Both written using jquery. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: The second one is pretty close, but still uses structured markup, and "jump-scrolling".

Comment: What do you mean by "structured markup"?
Did you see my other comment here? I used that on a live site and I am almost happy about it (it jump scrolls like you called it, but its the best I found).

Answer (score 1):

I am using currently:  http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/plugins/jdNewsScroll/1.1/

Which does seem to do also what you requested.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [Glimmer](http://visitmix.com/lab/glimmer).  A new designer tool to help generate all the code needed for cool UI widgets like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should try http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/autoscroll.html

The Problem is that it is not scrolling smoothly from the end to the beginning, but jumps to the start... Maybe you can edit the code for your requirements...

EDIT:

--> http://www.maaki.com/thomas/SmoothDivScroll/index.html

Its a little tutorial for autoscrolling using jQuery. Thr problem is, its supposed to be used with a div and just works horizontally. But it should be no problem on changing the code to make it scroll vertically if you have some javascript experience.

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not be able to achieve this using the [Cycle plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/). Either by using it's impressive API or by extending it a bit.