# How to create continuous scrolling content using Jquery .animate() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, marquee, scroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing circular scroller in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812049/implementing-circular-scroller-in-jquery)

I want to create vertical scroller, which will work exactly like marquee. But I want it to be continuous, like when we use marquee the whole content comes back only after it completely goes up, but I want it to be continuous.

this is what I have... http://jsfiddle.net/JWfaf/1/

I want only in one direction and keep on scrolling. I hope I have cleared what I want to achieve

HTML

```
<div class="con">
   <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
       <li></li>
   </ul>
</div>​
```

JavaScript

```
function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
$(targetElement).animate({ marginTop: "+=250px"},
{
    duration: speed,
    complete: function ()
    {
        targetElement.animate({ marginTop: "-=250px" },
        {
            duration: speed,
            complete: function ()
            {
                animatethis(targetElement, speed);
            }
        });
    }
});
};

animatethis($('.con ul li:first-child'), 10000);​
```

Comment: @RobertKoritnik I checked the questions, but the answers are not solving the problem, most of the links posted in those answers are broken.

Comment: @vikasdevde: Accepted answer's links are still both working and show vertical circular scrolling what you'er after. In a bit different variety but I'm sure they'd be helpful if you checked code into detail.

Comment: @vikasdevde: why wait for this question answers? There're other questions of yours that have been sufficiently answered and should be accepted. **Go and do your part if you want us to do ours...**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Working Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/rNXs9/1/

HTML :

```
<div id="verticalScroller">
    <div>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
    <div>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
    <div>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
    <div>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
</div>
​
```

CSS:

```
#verticalScroller {
    position: absolute;
    width:52px;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#verticalScroller > div {
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
​
```

JS :

```
window.verticalScroller = function($elem) {
    var top = parseInt($elem.css("top"));
    var temp = -1 * $('#verticalScroller > div').height();
    if(top < temp) {
        top = $('#verticalScroller').height()
        $elem.css("top", top);
    }
    $elem.animate({ top: (parseInt(top)-60) }, 600, function () {
      window.verticalScroller($(this))
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $("#verticalScroller > div").each(function () {
          $(this).css("top", i);
          i += 60;
          window.verticalScroller($(this));
    });
});

​
```

Comment: Awwww you beat me to it :P. I forked your version so it has linear easing. http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/N9PWn/

Comment: @howderek you made it clean and flawless...

Comment: @howderek  can I have little more favor, I have now added stop function to stop animation on hover, but cant figure out how to resume animation after mouseout. http://jsfiddle.net/testtracker/4whf6/2/

Comment: I won't be able to get on SO with a comp for a while (right now im on kindle) but you should try wrapping the animation in an if statement that allows the animation to run if a var `running` is equal to 1. Then use the mouseover and mouseout to make `running` 0 and 1

Comment: Nice solution. I've extended it a bit, and allowed variable item height, scroll pauses on mouse over, and multiple marquees per page: https://jsfiddle.net/y3uoepxx/ . I've also published it as a JQuery plugin on Github: https://github.com/aoloe/jquery-verticalscroll .

Comment: It was a great help. Though, I have found that the scrolling divs get overlapped when more than 4 child divs are used for scrolling. Here is changed version http://jsfiddle.net/82jge5v5/2/

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/yY5SP/) you are fine sir.

### The Code

JS:

```
function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
    $(targetElement).animate({ marginTop: "300px"},
    {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function ()
        {
            $(targetElement).css('marginTop','-450px');
            animatethis(targetElement, speed);
        }
    });
};

animatethis($('.con ul li:first-child'), 10000);​
```

CSS:

```
ul{display:block;width:110px;float:left;height:310px;background:#eee;overflow:hidden;}
li{display:block;width:100px;height:100px;background:#DDD;border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;margin-bottom:5px;}
.con{display:block;width:200px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="click">click</a>
<div class="con">
<ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>   
</ul></div>​
```

Comment: this is somewhat nearby. its going completely down and then its coming back, I want the li which getting hidden at the bottom immediately join at the top to keep continuous flow.

Comment: Ahh I see, well that will be a much more difficult problem ;D

Comment: trying from last 3 hours, hopes are alive with SO. I hope someone comes with a desired solution.. BTW thanks for helping...+1 for this

Comment: I am currently in the process of building this infinite scroller :D. I see it as a challenge for me.

Comment: Ok, right now I'm building an API to dynamically create a slider.

Comment: I hope you post here with your solution.

Comment: I will, I've got seamless scrolling, now i'm just trying to change the content.